# Create interface function with custom object

Tags: php, class, interface, theory

Is there an oppotunity to create an interface function in PHP, where a parameter requires to be an object, but not specified, what object it has to be?

Now my code looks like this:

```
interface Container {
    public static function add(\Employee $element);
}
```

Right now I can just implement the function with a parameter, which requires an instance from "Employee". When I now implement it in a class it looks like this:

```
class EmployeeContainer implements Container {
    public static function add(\Employee $element) {
        $pnr = $element->getPNR();
    }
}
```

When I create another class, that implements Container and set the required Object for example to Trainee, the PHP compiler throws an error:

```
class TraineeContainer implements Container {
    public static function add(\Trainee $element) {
        $pnr = $element->getPNR();
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Declaration of TraineeContainer::add($element) must be
>   compatible with Container::add(Employee $element)

Is there a way to set in the interface the required object to a custom object?

**Why I want this?**

Many IDE's supporting this form of instance description to suggest methods based on an object.

Comment: you can use same base class for Trainee and Employee and then use that class as argument in interface

Comment: @ChetanAmeta Can you show an example, I can't imagine it.

Comment: take a look at example in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custome object argument is not possible in interface but you can achieve it in other way.

create a common base class

```
class SomeBaseClass{

}
```

extend your classes

```
class Employee extends SomeBaseClass{

}

class Trainee extends SomeBaseClass{

}
```

then use `SomeBaseClass` as argument in your interface

```
interface Container {
    public static function add(SomeBaseClass $element);
}

class EmployeeContainer implements Container {
    public static function add(SomeBaseClass $element) {
        $pnr = $element->getPNR();
    }
}

class TraineeContainer implements Container {
    public static function add(SomeBaseClass $element) {
        $pnr = $element->getPNR();
    }
}
```

It seems you have `getPNR` common function so you can create an abstract class or interface and use that in your child classes.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. Only way is you should check argument type inside your method:

```
public static function add($element) {
    if(!$element instanceof \Trainee) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("your exception message");
    }

    $pnr = $element->getPNR();
}
```